# How to recover if Bridging Header deleted out of Build Settings?

Tags: xcode, swift, bridging-header

In my swift project, I accidentally removed my reference to the bridging header out of the section in "Build Settings" for the project. Now, Xcode can't find the file (even though I see it in my project navigator). What can I do to resolve this? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Xcode has build-in support for Git, use it. Also add backups, Time Machine is easy to setup, just get a cheap external drive. Next time there is an error you may loos everything. Consider this loss a warning, heed it.

Answer (score 0):

Go into your target's build settings, and do a search for `bridge`, you should see an option that says `Objective-C Bridging Header`, add the path to your file there.

This is how mine looks, in case you are not sure how to point to it,

```
APP/APP-Bridging-Header.h
```

Comment: I think I accidentally deleted that because it doesn't show up when I search for bridge...? Any suggestions?

Comment: I haven't tried this, but I read somewhere that if you delete that setting, and remove the file (I suggest you make a backup of it), and try to add an ObjC file, it will give you the option to auto configure the bridging header. Then you can copy the old one into the one generated by Xcode.